# Tomcat server not getting full resource file

Tags: java, jquery, tomcat, datatable

I have a tomcat instance that has a JAVA Spring solution deployed. Behind the scenes I am using this minifier to minify resources on the fly:

https://jango.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/js-minify-filter-in-java/

The problem I am seeing is after I have this setup and everything was working I added datatables to my solution. Now I am seeing an issue where the 2 of the datatables.min.js files are not being returned completely. For example for the jquery.datatables.min.js file the end of the file when I hit the url for the resource looks like this:

return bo.fn.datatable

But the file on the server (when I look directly) ends like this:

return h.fn.datatable});

So natuarlly I get these console errors:

[image]

Now I thought this could be an issue with the minify process on an already minified file, so I edited the minify solution to skip over .min.js files, but still the same result. I even tried using the non minified version for both of these files, but still the same result (both when they were and were not run through the minify process). I have placed some output statements on the minify process like below:

```
log.debug("REQUEST URL: " + requestURI);
log.debug("COMPRESSION LENGTH: " + compressed.length());
log.debug("COMPRESSION VALUE: " + compressed);
log.debug("Value that is uses: " + compressed.substring(0, compressed.length()));
```

But everything seems to be working. The value for the file that is printed out in the logs is correct (full file).

Has anyone seen this before? Any hints or anything what it could be? It might be worth nothing that when I deploy these to my local instance of tomcat there is no issue. It is only when it is deployed on this server running a different tomcat instance.

Let me know if anything is unclear or needs further explaining.